# Running papermill I get a FileNotFound Error

Tags: papermill

I'm running `papermill` 2.1.0  in a newly created virtual environment in Mac OS

When I execute a simple notebook I get: `FileNotFoundError`, referring to and old file that no longer exists.

```
papermill 59848931.ipynb 59848931-out.ipynb
```

I get the following:

```
Input Notebook:  59848931.ipynb
Output Notebook: 59848931-out.ipynb
Executing:   0%|                                                                                                                                         | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?cell/s]Failed to run command:
['/Users/user/Documents/Development/python/virtual_environments/udemy_tensorflow_venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', '/var/folders/p2/jh8vcbv51ks2gzvfx3dw1bd000_wjb/T/tmp3cf56dkh.json', '--HistoryManager.hist_file=:memory:']
    PATH='/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/bin:/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda/bin:/Users/user/homebrew/bin:/Users/user/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/:/usr/local/git/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/user/Documents/Development'
    with kwargs:
{'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': None, 'start_new_session': True}

Executing:   0%|                                                                                                                                         | 0/2 [00:01<?, ?cell/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/bin/papermill", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(papermill())
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/cli.py", line 235, in papermill
    execution_timeout=execution_timeout,
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/execute.py", line 104, in execute_notebook
    **engine_kwargs
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 49, in execute_notebook_with_engine
    return self.get_engine(engine_name).execute_notebook(nb, kernel_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 343, in execute_notebook
    cls.execute_managed_notebook(nb_man, kernel_name, log_output=log_output, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 402, in execute_managed_notebook
    return PapermillNotebookClient(nb_man, **final_kwargs).execute()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/clientwrap.py", line 36, in execute
    with self.setup_kernel(**kwargs):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 404, in setup_kernel
    self.start_new_kernel_client(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 37, in wrapped
    result = loop.run_until_complete(coro(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 467, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 375, in async_start_new_kernel_client
    await ensure_async(self.km.start_kernel(extra_arguments=self.extra_arguments, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 57, in ensure_async
    result = await obj
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 542, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = await self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 523, in _launch_kernel
    res = launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/notebooks/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Documents/Development/python/virtual_environments/udemy_tensorflow_venv/bin/python3': '/Users/user/Documents/Development/python/virtual_environments/udemy_tensorflow_venv/bin/python3'
```

I reinstall Python3, papermill and virtualenv and same issue

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled my IPython kernel

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```